# jQuery Counter Remains at "0" and doesn't count up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a certain section of my website animate a count up. However, when I load the website nothing runs and it remains at "0". I have jQuery at the start of my HTML script in the head section `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },
    {
      duration: 8000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 showinmbl">
  <h4 class="txt-primary  fs40 mb-0" class="counter" data-count="150" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;">0</h4>
  <p class="fs30 weight500" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;">Wins</p>
</div>
```

Why isn't it counting?

Comment: Does your script appear in your HTML before or after that `<div>`? If before, then `$(".counter")` will be empty, and the code won't do anything.

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to find the errors on the console. You need to wait for stuff to load before you can ask JS/jquery to access it so either put your JS at the end or put it in a function which is run when everything has been loaded.

Comment: @Pointy - It's right at the bottom of the document just before I close the body tag.

Comment: @AHaworth - Nothing shows in my console.

Comment: `$({countNum: $this.text()}).animate`?

Answer (score 1):

You have set `class` attribute twice in your `h4` tag. That's why it's not working. Check this working example here.

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },
    {
      duration: 8000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 showinmbl">
  <h4 class="txt-primary  fs40 mb-0 counter" data-count="150" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;">0</h4>
  <p class="fs30 weight500" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;">Wins</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of your HTML code. this line:

```
  <h4 class="txt-primary  fs40 mb-0" class="counter" data-count="150" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;">0</h4>
```

You have set class attribute twice, here is the problem, you can change your *h4* tag like this and it will work:

```
  <h4 class="txt-primary fs40 mb-0 counter"  data-count="150" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;">0</h4>
```